# Brunch Compile non-"main" files in Bower components

Tags: highcharts, bower, brunch

### Short Version

Each package loaded by Bower has a whole lot of files, but Brunch is smart enough to only compile the files listed in each package's `main` property in its bower.json. That's great, but I find myself really needing one of those non-main files.

How can I tell Brunch to grab a specific file that would not otherwise be selected and then concatenate it onto the end of vendor.js?

### Long Version

I'm using Brunch to build my AngularJS app. Dependencies are loaded by Bower. The specific package that I'm struggling with is Highcharts. Bower gets it just fine, but Highcharts' bower.json lists only three specific files in its `main` property, so Brunch grabs just those three and puts them in vendors.js. However, I need to do drilldown charts, which require also loading drilldown.js, which is located at `bower_components/highcharts/modules/drilldown.js`. Brunch does not grab that file, and I can't seem to get it to do so.

Here is the relevant portion of my brunch config:

```
javascripts: {
  joinTo: {
    'assets/js/app.js': /^app/,
    'assets/js/vendor.js': /^bower_components/
  },
  order: {
    after: ['bower_components/highcharts/modules/drilldown.js']
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I can override the `main` property of the Highcharts bower.json in my own config. In my bower.json, I've put:

```
"overrides": {
    "highcharts": {
        "main": [
            "highcharts.js",
            "highcharts-more.js",
            "modules/drilldown.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle this, so if anybody has a better idea I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: This is the correct way when using Brunch's bower integration.